# How to capture printed data from my CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

Disclaimer: I am a first time "programmer" and this is my first project. Please be patient as I am still learning terminology along with everything else that goes with it.

I am trying to capture specific data from my CSV and input that data into my python script to tweet it out. (Im making a Twitter bot).

This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvDataFile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvDataFile))

print(data[25][2])
```

This lets me import my CSV and then select the column and row to which my tweet quote is.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
id_serial,id_season,quote,file_path,id_group,trigger_time
1,S1E01,"People say I am the best boss. They go ""god we've never worked at a place like this before. You're hilarious. And you get the best out of us.""",,001,09:00 AM EST
2,S1E01,I think this pretty much sums it up,/home/pi/Desktop/OfficialDundies/media/001.png,001,11:00 AM EST
```

I would like to be able to grab the "printed" quote and store it as a variable so I can recall it later. Ideally, my bot will grab the quote and check the "trigger_time" to see if it is time to tweet.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Pandas - it's generally a much easier and more efficient way to deal with CSV data than any parsing you'd write yourself.

You can find installation instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) and a short tutorial [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/10min.html).

You can read the file with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Then

```
df['quote']
```

will be a Series (think of it as a list of values with indices attached) that contains the quotes.

To access the "I think this" quote, you could use

```
print (df['quote'].iloc[1])
```

You'd probably want to use

```
df = df.set_index('id_serial')
```

so that the indices are your IDs, and then you could also access that quote with

```
print (df['quote'].loc[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at one line at a time like so:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvDataFile:
    for line in csv.DictReader(csvDataFile):
        print(line['quoted'])
        print(line['trigger_time'])
```

You can decide what to do from there, hopefully.

Comment: thanks @brunns! This helped a lot. This currently returns all of data at once. What if I wanted to only select the second row of information?